# Use launch args as variables in ROS2 launch file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to start a launch file with `ros2 launch` and pass it arguments that are used in the launch file, like for starting a node in debug mode or starting extra nodes if running in simulation. I hope to achieve something like this from ROS1:

```
<arg name="debug" default="false" />
<arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="" />
<arg if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="gdb --ex run --args" />
```

I have seen good examples for passing launch arguments through to node parameters using `launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument` but can't figure out using the launch args inside of the launch file itself. I am using Foxy on Ubuntu 20. This is the minimal launch file I am trying to get working

```
import os
import yaml
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

def generate_launch_description():
    debug_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('debug', default_value='false')
    debug_prefix = 'xterm -e gdb --args' if LaunchConfiguration('debug')=='true' else ''

    talker_node = Node(
        package='cpp_pubsub',
        executable='talker',
        prefix=[debug_prefix],
        output='screen'
    )

    listener_node = Node(
        package='cpp_pubsub',
        executable='listener',
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([ debug_arg, talker_node, listener_node ])
```

What I hope to be able to do eventually is `ros2 launch package file debug:='true'` or similiar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357397/use-launch-args-as-variables-in-ros2-launch-file/) by [APettinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/41977/apettinger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2020-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It cannot work as is because parsing is not yet done when the description is generated.

You can split your talker_node in 2 nodes:

- 1 with `condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(launch.LaunchConfiguration("debug"))` having the additional debug_prefix
- 1 with `condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(launch.LaunchConfiguration("debug"))` having no additional prefix

This is equivalent to the `<node if="$(arg debug) .../>"` and `<node unless="$(arg debug) .../>"` existing with the XML syntax of launch files.

---

Originally posted by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) with karma: 122 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1